# In factor analysis, how can we address observations that are missing because the screening question was negative?

Tags: factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

I have a fairly large sample ($n= $ 3000) of adolescents answering various questions on their psychological well-being. These questions are supposed to address various categories of psychopathology. For example, regarding depression, you can ask 9 questions that address various aspects of depression; however, two of those questions are screening questions, meaning that if the response to both are negative, we no longer proceed to ask the seven remaining questions.

This poses a challenge as how to include those seven questions in factor analysis, as those who respond negatively to the two screening questions have no values for the 7 remaining questions.

Comment: If some respondents were not asked a question because they are not qualified to response how do you think of some valid value possible in that case for them?

Comment: I don't see either why it makes sense to include them or how you could defensibly do it any way. For example, suppose you  impute seven constants for the answers they might have given; then you just have a dataset that is a massive blob (so many people, all the same in their answers, real or imagined)  and everybody else. The results can't fail to be partly an artefact of some arbitrary assumption. Conversely, if this isn't what you intend, please tell us more. It's like asking me if I smoke tobacco (no) or have ever smoked tobacco (no) and finding that all further questions have no answers.

Comment: What is the rating scale and anchors used for the non-screening items (e.g., 1 -7; 1-5; 0-9;, etc., Strongly disagree - Strongly agree; Very inaccurate - Very accurate, etc.)?